# Download link to android SDK WITH Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

Please help me with the download link to android SDK **WITH Eclipse** (any version just before android studio release is fine) because i'm having a serious problem with my existing projects in android studio

Comment: The link I had posted were referencing older versions.  See answer below for newer version links..

Comment: Yeah, they make it hard to find it since Android Studio came out.  I stumbled upon that link a while ago, and made sure to save it for future reference.  Glad I could help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ahh, just found the link I was looking for.

Links to bundles:

> linux 64 bit vm:
>
> http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702.zip
>
> linux 32 bit vm:
>   http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140702.zip
>
> mac:
>   http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702.zip
>
> win32:
>   http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702.zip
>
> win64:
>   http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702.zip

Source: 
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72584